# Maximum call stack size exceeded in streamChunksOfSourceMap.js

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 12.2.0, and when hit to start i gave the following error

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing).../Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/helpers/streamChunksOfSourceMap.js:21
        const lines = source.match(SPLIT_LINES_REGEX);
                             ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.match (<anonymous>)
    at streamChunksOfSourceMapFull (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/helpers/streamChunksOfSourceMap.js:21:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/helpers/streamChunksOfSourceMap.js:389:6)
    at SourceMapSource.streamChunks (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/SourceMapSource.js:211:11)
    at module.exports (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/helpers/streamChunks.js:13:17)
    at ReplaceSource.streamChunks (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ReplaceSource.js:176:44)
    at module.exports (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/helpers/streamChunks.js:13:17)
    at ConcatSource.streamChunks (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ConcatSource.js:112:55)
    at module.exports (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/helpers/streamChunks.js:13:17)
    at streamAndGetSourceAndMap (/Users/.../node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/helpers/streamAndGetSourceAndMap.js:27:53)
```

Its very strange, because this is so random. I nothing change just rebuild it again and again, and its everything working well. I stop the app, rerun, than this error appearing.

I raised the maximum call stack size too, but not helped.

I think its maybe a bug, because if I clean/force clean cache, and delete node modules, and reinstall it, its not working, when I do this again and again, its working, and starting this randomly error headache again.

I found the problem, but I don't know why? The `streamChunksOfSourceMap.js` basically use Angular to create sourcemaps. If I set in `angular.json` the development option `configurations` `sourceMap` property to false, everything is fine. but without source map the debugging is harder.

Someone faced this problem before?

Comment: It seems there is a recursive call to something which be exhausting the memory.

Comment: could you try creating a production build? `ng build`?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara if there is a recursive call, than why working everything sometimes?


@MaartenDev The `ng build` just thinking, no error, but don't do anything, but this is random too, sometimes the building working sometimes don't.

Comment: I found the problem, but I don't know why? If I set in `angular.json` the development option `configurations` `sourceMap` property to false, everything is fine. but without source map the debugging is harder.

Comment: You might have changed the configuration in angular. Its hard to debug the things without having sufficient details.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Finally, its working. The problem was the`~1.32.12` version of the sass, I switched to `~1.37.5` and now everything is working well. Its very strange, because that's why I got random errors, and never got any sass/scss error in the project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with webpack, tracked [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-sources/issues/131)